# How do I solve error code 1242 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database, I have two tables. I am trying to sum up the scores in the two tables. First table named `term2` has a particular column named `Total_Score,` and a column named `StudentID`. The second table named `overall` also has a column named `Total_Score` and a column named `StudentID`. What I want to do is UPDATE the value of `overall.Total_Score` by summing up the values in `term2.Total_Score` with the values in `overall.Total_Score`, and place the result in `overall.Total_Score`. Below is the code I am using, but when I have more than one row, I get the error above. Have a look at my code and assist, please. Thank you in advance.

```
UPDATE overall SET Total_Score = ( SELECT (
ot.Total_Score + op.Total_Score
) AS Total_Score
FROM (
SELECT StudentID, Total_Score
FROM term2
GROUP BY StudentID
) AS ot
INNER JOIN (
SELECT StudentID, Total_Score
FROM overall
GROUP BY StudentID
) AS op ON ( op.StudentID = ot.StudentID ) )
```

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax and grouping subquery as second data source.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below - you need `an update join` and your syntax was incorrect

```
update overall o inner join
(
SELECT op.StudentID, 
       sum(ot.total_score) as Total_Score_ot,
       sum(op.total_score) as Total_Score_op
FROM term2 ot inner join overall op on op.StudentID = ot.StudentID 
GROUP BY op.StudentID
) as o1 on o.StudentID = o1.StudentID
SET Total_Score=Total_Score_ot+Total_Score_op
```

Comment: Thank you Fahmi. It works perfiectly as I desired. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to replace the `overall` value with the calculated value.  The key idea is to aggregate *before* joining the tables together:

```
update overall o join
       (select t.StudentId, sum(t.total_score) as total_score
        from term2 t
        group by t.StudentId
       ) t
       using (StudentId)
    set o.Total_Score = t.Total_Score;
```

If you want to *increment* the stored value by the total in `term2`, then use:

```
    set o.Total_Score = o.Total_Score + t.Total_Score;
```

If instead you want to *replace* the stored value for *all* students, even those with no rows in `term2`, then use `left join`:

```
update overall o left join
       (select t.StudentId, sum(t.total_score) as total_score
        from term2 t
        group by t.StudentId
       ) t
       using (StudentId)
    set o.Total_Score = coalesce(t.Total_Score, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. I know this will work as it looks similar to the solution suggested by Fahmi.

Comment: @scottser . . . The solutions are quite different.  If you notice, this version has only one `join` in it -- the aggregate subquery does not have a `join`.  In addition, it simply assigns the value (or increments it in place).  I provided an answer because I think this is a better solution to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement your solution and see. Appreciate your clarification as well.